# IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

My database design is like that:

Column Name: Name ,Data Type: varchar(50)

When i cast data type it into visual studio it got  exception

IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        return reader.Cast<System.Data.IDataRecord>()
                            .Select(x => new JobInfo()
                            {

                                Name = x.GetString(0),


                            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

`x.GetString(0)` is probably your issue. Arrays are 0-based in C#. If the item has no elements, the trying to get the "0th" one (the first) will cause an exception to be thrown. It's the same thing as trying to get the 9th element in an 8-element array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve a record, when no record exists. Check whether your datareader has data first:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
  //get the record here
}
```

Comment: `.Select()` will return an empty collection if there are no records. I don't think this would be the issue.